# How to make the regressor of LASSO consistent?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, mathematical-statistics, lasso, ridge-regression

Suppose there is one regressor $X$ ith a sample so that $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2=n$. And suppose the OLS estimator of $Y$ on $X$ (no intercept) is consistent. What condition does $\lambda$ need to satisfy to make LASSO consistent? What about ridge?

Comment: You should have a look to this paper http://users.stat.umn.edu/~zouxx019/Papers/adalasso.pdf where an adaptive lasso is defined. They also discuss why the lasso estimator is not consistent but the adaptive lasso is.